# How can you connect multiple monitors to one temperature sensor?

Tags: sensor, temperature, monitor

I have two monitors I want to connect to one temperature sensor. I tried connecting the sensor wires in parallel but it only outputs error. Sometimes the power doesn't even turn on. I'm guessing the signal can't be split in multiples. Anyone have an idea on how to read a single sensor to multiple monitors? What do I need? What do I have to purchase?

Temperature sensor using MF55 type of NTC thermistor, epoxy potting.

Operating voltage: 4.5-28V

[Here is more info on the monitor.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01L1DLPWG)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to be clear on what type of "temperature sensor" you are using. Is this a thermocouple? RTD? PT100, PT1000? Type-J/K...? Also be clear on what type of "monitor" you are using is.

Comment: Thanks @RonBeyer. Edited

Comment: NTC thermisters require an excitation voltage. Both meters trying to excite in parallel will not work.

Comment: You could very well damage your equipment with this attempt.

Comment: Does other types of thermistors allow parallel? Is there a way to network the signal?

Comment: You have linked to an Amazon ad instead of a datasheet. That means we have no circuit information and no real clue as to how the device works internally. One of the reasons for the low price is the lack of documentation. "*No datasheet? No sale!*"

Comment: @transistor are there multiple ways to read a ntc?

Comment: @Passerby, probably. One end of the NTC could be connected to GND or V+ or some sort of floating circuit or internal virtual ground. Knowing this might give the (slight) possibility of monitoring the other if only the voltage monitoring circuit was used without the current source, etc.

Comment: I took it apart as much I could and added pictures

Comment: I would take the most inexpensive solution and use two probes, they you have a backup reading incase one fails. the parts and your labor will cost a lot more then the second meter. You can purchase commercial equipment that will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two readouts from one sensor by connecting the sensor to a transmitter. The transmitter does not need to have its own readout but it can send a 4 to 20 mA signal to two indicating meters connected in series.

You need to look carefully at the specifications to assure that the meters are designed to be connected in series. You also need to determine if the transmitter has a built-in power supply or it that much be purchased separately.

Here are examples of a 4-20 mA temperature transmitter and a loop-powered indicating meter.

[Transmitter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RKJ29LX)

[Meter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00QKW8D38)

Comment: Can you show me an example, please?

Comment: See addition to answer.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the back board contains a power supply and some resistors
and the the front board contains the display circuit

something you could try would be to disconnect the thite wire of the triple wires from one meter and connect it to the white of the other. that should make both meters display the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they're using a 10K NTC thermistor.

You can try removing R11 (0 ohm) from one of the two meters and see if that works. They may not read exactly the same but it should be reasonably close.